# When trying to establish a second baseline in the Compass Vertical Rhythm module the line-height is the same for both baselines

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

So far I was using Compass 0.12.x and i had a working mixin for switching baselines for the Compass Vertical Rhythm module. When i try to apply that mixin to Compass v1.0.1 the line-height for the two baselines stays the same. The reduced code looks like that:

```
@import 'compass';

@mixin use-baseline($new-base-size, $new-line-height) {
    // Save the baseline context
    $initial-font-size: $base-font-size;
    $initial-line-height: $base-line-height;
    // Apply the new context
    $base-font-size: $new-base-size;
    $base-line-height: $new-line-height;
    @content;
    // Go back to the baseline context
    $base-font-size: $initial-font-size;
    $base-line-height: $initial-line-height;
}

$vr-base-font-size: 20px;
$vr-base-line-height:28px;

$vr-750-font-size: 26px;
$vr-750-line-height:37px;
$vr-750: $vr-750-font-size $vr-750-line-height;

$base-font-size: $vr-base-font-size;
$base-line-height: $vr-base-line-height;

@include establish-baseline($vr-base-font-size);
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) { 
    @include use-baseline($vr-750...) {
        @include establish-baseline($vr-750-font-size);
    }
}
```

The according pen is http://codepen.io/rpkoller/pen/lrBHK . The resulting code in Compass 1.0.1 is:

```
html {
  font-size: 125%;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  html {
    font-size: 162.5%;
    line-height: 1.4em; }
}
```

In Compass 0.12.x it was

```
html {
  font-size: 125%;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}

@media (min-width: 46.875em) {
  html {
    font-size: 162.5%;
    line-height: 1.42308em;
}
```

So what is causing that Compass 1.0.1 is returning the identical line-heights? Rounding as a reason wouldn't make sense, cuz if you input more differing line-height values, like 100px and 25 px, the output is still the same for both baselines ( see http://codepen.io/rpkoller/pen/qjdsa ).

***Update:*** 
Ok I finally figured things out. Turned out the behaviour was due to the changes introduced in Sass 3.4. You have to change the use-baseline mixin accordingly:

```
@mixin use-baseline($new-base-size, $new-line-height) {
    // Save the baseline context
    $initial-font-size: $base-font-size;
    $initial-line-height: $base-line-height;
    // Apply the new context
    $base-font-size: $new-base-size !global;
    $base-line-height: $new-line-height !global;
    @content;
    // Go back to the baseline context
    $base-font-size: $initial-font-size;
    $base-line-height: $initial-line-height;
}
```